# Writing a cross-platform/cross-webserver API for any type of Database

Tags: database, web-services, api, cross-platform

Well, as the title suggest, I was wondering if there is a way to write such an API. For a project I need to develop API's for multiple clients, that all run different webservers, operating systems and have different database types.
Instead of writing an API for each one specifically, is there a way to write a cross-platform solution?

I can imagine this would be possible in some low-level programming languages. So if anyone has a clue, theory or other suggestion, please let me know!

EDIT:
I don't think I explained it well enough. There are different clients (as in real people), who have websites with databases attached. Some of them run Windows with Azure, some of them run Ubuntu with Apache, etc etc. Some of them use MySQL, SQLite, etc etc. I want to know if there is a way to write an API that would work on each and every one of them, regardless of the OS and database type. Like using PERL, Python, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a set of instructions and execute them on a virtual machine for each environment. Like how java works. But if you are asking "can i get my .net code to run in php?" then the answer is no. It depends on your situation but you could also consider providing a common interface to your service, e.g xml or json over http.

Comment: I don't think I explained it well enough. There are different clients (as in real people), who have websites with databases attached. Some of them run Windows with Azure, some of them run Ubuntu with Apache, etc etc. Some of them use MySQL, SQLite, etc etc. I want to know if there is a way to write an API that would work on each and every one of them, regardless of the OS and database type. Like using PERL, Python, or something similar.

Comment: You at least need to define the API/Language and handle execution of the commands on all the different environments by writing virtual machines (or equivalent) for your language.  Some things will not even be possible to handle like extensions of SQL which do bespoke things.  So no, you cant succesfully (and shouldn't try to) write such a generic wrapper which solves everything.